# GORM FirstOrCreate never updates boolean fields

Tags: go, go-gorm

In my model I have fields like this:

```
HidePricingFromProfile     bool    `json:"hidePricingFromProfile"`
```

When I update the model in DB:

```
store.storage.DB.
    Where("artist_account_id = ?", m.ArtistAccountID).
    Assign(model).
    FirstOrCreate(m).
    Error
```

It updates boolean fields only to true values.

this field is defined in DB like this:

```
hide_pricing_from_profile boolean default false not null
```

Answer (score 0):

From [doc](https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Default-Values)

> NOTE all fields having a zero value, like 0, '', false or other zero
> values, won’t be saved into the database but will use its default
> value
> The zero value of `bool` is `false` that's why it not updated. You need to use pointer of `bool` which zero value is `nil` then `false` value will be updated in the database.

```
HidePricingFromProfile     *bool    `json:"hidePricingFromProfile"`
```